# Problem with install node.js in terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my error:
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yaml failed, reason:
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

How fix it?

I tried install the node.js again.
I tried change network sets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm config list` and check if you are behind any proxies. If you are, you'll have to remove them.